# Flask redirecting to wrong links

Tags: python, html, flask

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark align-items-start sidebar sidebar-dark accordion bg-gradient-primary p-0">
            <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column p-0"><a
                    class="navbar-brand d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center sidebar-brand m-0" href="#">
                    <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15"><i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i></div>
                    <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3"><span>hEALTHGENIC</span></div>
                </a>
                <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">
                <ul class="navbar-nav text-light" id="accordionSidebar">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="/"><i
                                class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login"><i
                                class="far fa-user-circle"></i><span>Login</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline"><button class="btn rounded-circle border-0"
                        id="sidebarToggle" type="button"></button></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

> The above code waas stored in index.html.
>
> The flask code(python) was:

from flask import Flask, render_template, request

```
local_server = True
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html') 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

> On clicking the dashboard button, the link which is returned is
> /index.html instead of / . Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

When you creating a href's to route in Flask you should use `url_for` function in HTML file:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark align-items-start sidebar sidebar-dark accordion bg-gradient-primary p-0">
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column p-0"><a
                class="navbar-brand d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center sidebar-brand m-0" href="#">
                <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15"><i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i></div>
                <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3"><span>hEALTHGENIC</span></div>
            </a>
            <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-light" id="accordionSidebar">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><i
                            class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"></li>
                <li class="nav-item"></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('login') }}"><i
                            class="far fa-user-circle"></i><span>Login</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline"><button class="btn rounded-circle border-0"
                    id="sidebarToggle" type="button"></button></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Bro, same issue persists, it still navigates to http://127.0.0.1:5000/index.html on the local server

Comment: @UtkarshA did you import `url_for` in the main file where your routes are? otherwise makes no sense (unless you just run your own code again)

Comment: actually there was some cache issues, thats why it wasnt working, after closing the tab , it worked again oof